# how to use real function of inheritance class when it's in pointer c++

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism

```
class A{
public:
    int aaa;
    A(){aaa=0};
    void print() const;
};
class B : public A{
public:
    int bbb;
    B(){aaa=0,bbb=12};
    void print() const;
};

void A::print() const{
    cout << aaa << endl;
}
void B::print() const{
    cout << bbb << endl;
}

int main(){
    A *ptr[2];
    ptr[0]=new B();
    ptr->print(); //it will show 0 from aaa but how to show 12 from bbb.
}
```

I want to show 12 (in class B : public A) not 0 in class A.
Someone know much of pointer and inheritance and polymorphism please help me to know how thanks!

Comment: Your code does not compile.  "error: expected ';' before '}' two places.

Comment: After adding the accepted answer's "virtual" modifier to A::print(), you can still access A::print with "ptr[0]->A::print()" which show's the '0' of A::aaa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `virtual` functions. In other terms:

```
class A{
public:
    int aaa;
    A(){aaa=0;};
    virtual void print() const;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You must make the function virtual. Use keyword *virtual* in the function definition

Comment: also, `ptr[0]` not `ptr` in `ptr->print()`

Answer (score 0):

Make the function `virtual` which will delay the binding of function name to its body.

```
virtual void print() const;
```